# SQL query to join 2 tables and export to Excel from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I work on phpmyadmin portal for my company, from which I export data from 2 tables in seperate CSV files, then copy them to main xlsm file to process the data in tables and create reports from them.

How can i combine these 2 tables and export them directly to my main file?

Also, these data are are custom exported from certain rows only and not all, and they tend to change as the data update in the table.

I do not have the server name though.

Comment: What methods have you attempted thus far?

Comment: I down 2 different tables as CSV and then map them in excel through various formulas. Though it is pretty easy to do that, i was hoping to do it in single go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below-

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2 
INTO OUTFILE 'e:\\myfile.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id;
```

Note: If you are working on linux platform then change accordingly.